# How can I use SAX interface of libxml2 to parse streamed xml file?

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I have a requirement of parsing big xml files from server. We currently use a stream to read these file which looks like below:

```
class stream
{
    size_t getSize();
    size_t read(void* buf, size_t offset, size_t size);
}
```

But I could just find two interfaces:

```
XMLPUBFUN int XMLCALL
        xmlSAXUserParseFile (xmlSAXHandlerPtr sax,
                     void *user_data,
                     const char *filename);
XMLPUBFUN int XMLCALL
        xmlSAXUserParseMemory   (xmlSAXHandlerPtr sax,
                     void *user_data,
                     const char *buffer,
                     int size);
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use libxml2's [push parser interface](http://www.xmlsoft.org/library.html#Invoking1). Initialize the parser by calling [xmlCreatePushParserCtxt](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCreatePushParserCtxt). Then read your data from the server and process it piece by piece with [xmlParseChunk](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseChunk). This will invoke the SAX callbacks. Finally, free the parser context with [xmlFreeParserCtxt](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlFreeParserCtxt).

Comment: That works! Thanks! BTW, Is it necessnary to call xmlCleanupParser after every document parsed to avoid memory leak?

Comment: @JimYang No, you don't have to call `xmlCleanupParser`. This function is only useful when checking for memory leaks. In this case, it *must only be called once* right before exiting your program.

Comment: So I should call **xmlCleanupParser** at least once(after last use of libxml2 or before program exited) or libxml2 will have something un-released?

Comment: @JimYang If you're not sure, don't call `xmlCleanupParser` at all. It's only useful to suppress false positives from tools like *valgrind*.